# Bootstrap - resize specific column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I don't know how to make this kind of col 3 and 6 size.

[image]

Middle column has no padding, but it is not enough.

I was trying to make different sizes of col.

```
@media (min-width:992px){   
    .col-md-6 { width: 52,5641%;}
    .col-md-3 { width: 23,7179%;}
}
```

but no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Bootstrap you dont need to add `media queries` or your own `width`, just use the BS grid system ([you can read more here](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)) and let it handle all the tough work. Based on your picture a 3 column layout would use something like this:

```
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-3</div>
      <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
      <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-3</div>
  </div>
```

Make sure you columns total 12 like above (3+6+3) If you need extra padding in between columns just add a nested DIV and apply the spacing you want to those.

```
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="myclass">
           this will have extra padding
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
      <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-3</div>
  </div>

  .myclass {
     padding: 20px;
  }
```

**Updated**

Based on your comment if you want column 6 to be slightly larger than it is you will either need to expand that column and "shrink" the outer 2 columns to something like this:

```
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">.col-md-2</div>
      <div class="col-md-8">.col-md-8</div>
      <div class="col-md-2">.col-md-2</div>
  </div>
```

If that's not what you are going for then you can create your own table within bootstrap.

```
  <div class="row">
      <div class="custom-col">My custom left side</div>
      <div class="custom-main">my main column</div>
      <div class="custom-col">My custom right side</div>
  </div>
```

Sizing each of the column as you need.

Comment: No, you didn't uderstand my question. I need to expand column md-6 for    gitter size in both direction. If I put padding-right-15px and padding-left:-15px is not ok ;).

Comment: Thank you all for answers. Yes at the end I make my own table. I didn't know how to make this with bootstrap.

Comment: @tine glad you figured it out. As far as I understand the BS grid system is just that... a grid system. If the pre-defined sizes dont work for your needs then you have to build and size it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Bootstrap is not the best option for your problem. It works if only you can divide the screen in 12 equal parts. Rewrite this rule could break other stuff.

What about using flexboxes or other CSS framework more flexible?

Comment: No, I must use boostrap.;)

Comment: In that case, is there any way to add a new CSS class that override the default bootstrap behaviour? What if you crop a bit the green zone?